# Simultaneous API calls with independent callbacks

Tags: javascript, api, meteor, callback, simultaneous

I'd like to call multiple times the same API but with different keys to get results faster.

The thing is I need to not wait to receive the result from the first call to start the second call, etc...

The steps are :

1) I have an array with all the different keys.

2) This gets data from the API ("APIKeys" is the array that contains all the keys) :

```
_.map(APIKeys,function(value, index){
    var newCount = count+(25*index);
    parseResult(Meteor.http.get("http://my.api.com/content/search/scidir?query=a&count=25&start="+newCount+"&apiKey="+value+""));
});
```

3) I call a function (named "parseResult") that will format and filter the result I get from the API and save it into the database.

I want to call the function (step 3) without having to wait that I get the data from the API and continue with the other keys while the request is being made.

Do you know how I could do that with meteor ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this to use `HTTP.get()` in an async manner:

```
HTTP.get("http://my.api.com/content/search/scidir?query=a&count=25&start="+newCount+"&apiKey="+value+"", function (error, result) {
    // parse the result here
});
```

And see the docs here:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_get

Comment: I've already tried that but the problem is I want to launch all requests at the same time and let them run until they got the data and store it into the database. I've found a solution using Fiber and Future, it seems to work but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: I don't understand why what I wrote isn't a good solution but ok if you found a way to do it already

Comment: You're solution is correct but it's not really what I'm looking for. I need to do what you wrote but 1000x at the same time. Therefore I have to find a solution to not having to wait for the first API call to end to start the second call, etc ... and as the API is slow I have to wait the data before store it into the database. It's quite difficult to explain but in general I just have to manage the event loop with Future and Fiber, it works like charm now :)